# How does the conditional（れば） + 一緒 structure work?

Tags: meaning

How does the conditional + 一緒　structure work?

This person ate a raw prawn and was then berated by his friends in the following exchange.

> 「さ、さすがに生は……どうかと思うぞ」
>
> 「残酷な食べ方ね」
>
> 「残酷も何も……**口に入れれば一緒**だと思うんだけどな」

Comment: Please always try to include your best translation attempt, or [your question may be closed as off-topic](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/5010). I assumed you got the meaning of 一緒 wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a special grammar pattern. This 一緒 means "the same" or "makes no difference" rather than "together". See the third definition [here](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%B8%80%E7%B7%92).

> 口に入れれば一緒だと思うんだけどな
>   Well, I think that (=eating something raw) makes no difference if/once it has been put into the mouth.